# How do I solve this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tables:

- `CUSTOMER` (CUSTOMER-NAME(P), CUSTOMER-STREET, CUSTOMER- CITY)
- `BRANCH` (BRANCH-NAME(P), BRANCH-CITY, ASSETS)
- `ACCOUNT` (ACCOUNT-NUMBER(P), BRANCH-NAME, BALANCE)
- `LOAN` (LOAN-NUMBER(P), BRANCH-NAME, AMOUNT)
- `DEPOSITOR` (CUSTOMER-NAME(P), ACCOUNT-NUMBER(P))
- `BORROWER` (CUSTOMER-NAME(P), LOAN-NUMBER(P))

The attributes marked with `P` are the primary key of the table.

The above is a relational schema and I have to write the SQL syntax for the following query:

- Find names of customers having account in all branches of "Noida" (where Noida is the name of a place)

  1. I tried solving this but the output came out to be those customers which have an account in some branch at Noida. How to do it for all?
  2. I am having a doubt in SQL that can we combine two relations even on non-primary key? For eg:

  `depositor.account-number = account.account-number and account.branch-name    = branch.branch-name`

In the above statement, `branch-name` is not the primary key for account but is for branch. Therefore, is the above right?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And what is `Noida` is that a `customer`? And does `branch` relate to `customer`? If yes, then how, what is the column in `branch` that references `customer`

Comment: I am using Oracle. And "Noida" is the name of a place. And branch is not related to customer.

Comment: Please post some sample data. How would anybody imagine `NOIDA` belongs to which column and which table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the right query

```
select *
from CUSTOMER c
where not exists (
        select BRANCH-NAME
        from BRANCH
        where BRANCH-CITY = 'Noida'
        minus
        select BRANCH-NAME
        from ACCOUNT 
            join DEPOSITOR d using (ACCOUNT-NUMBER)
        where d.CUSTOMER-NAME = c.CUSTOMER-NAME
    )
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am reading about joins as of now. I read about different kind of joins from here `http://www.sql-join.com/`. There's no `join` perse, there is inner join. Are the two same?

Comment: I hadn't clearly understood your question. I don't know if this is what you asked for, but  ...The NOT EXISTS clause executes an anti-join, and the JOIN clause without prefixes is implicitly considered an INNER JOIN